# NOTEPAD++ REGEX - Delete everything between static string and dynamic string

Tags: regex, notepad++

How would I remove everything between `<item_fifty>` and `### hid`, where `###` can be any number? I want to preserve the `<item_fifty>` and `### hid` so they're not deleted when I replace.

I want to convert this:

```
<item_fifty>jdfkjalskjfkajsdlfjkasdfkj### hid389208398</item_fifty>
```

to this:

```
<item_fifty>### hid389208398</item_fifty>
```

This is what I have so far

```
<item_fifty\>.*[0-9]{3} hid
```

The problem is it deletes the ### hid as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a positive lookahead:

```
.*(?=[0-9]{3} hid)
```

This should select up to but not including `### hid`.

Edit: Assuming you don't want to delete the `<item_fifty>`, use a look-behind as well:

```
(?<=<item_fifty>).*(?=[0-9]{3} hid)
```

Edit 2: To let `###` be any number of digits, this will do it:

```
(?<=<item_fifty>).*?(?=[0-9]+ hid)
```

The `?` in `.*?` causes the `*` to be non-greedy, that is, it will consume the least amount of the string necessary in order to match (normally it would consume as much as it could, including part of the numbers).

Comment: is there anyway to make the [0-9]{3} work with a number of any length?

Comment: Sure. `[0-9]+` will do it (as long as the length is greater than 0).

Comment: [0-9]+ selects up to ## if the number was ### in length .. anyway to exclude the number completely from being selected?

Comment: Yeah... change `.*` to `.*?` to make it non-greedy. See edit.

Answer (score 0):

Capture the text and reference it in the replace:

```
Search: <item_fifty\>.*([0-9]{3} hid)
Replace: \1
```

Or use a look-ahead:

```
Search: <item_fifty\>.*(?=[0-9]{3} hid)
```

Look aheads are non-consuming expressions.